# After I installed ccsm, my desktop not working properly. How to restore?

Tags: ccsm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I installed ccsm and as soon I clicked on preferences, everything hanged. After waiting for some time, I restarted my computer. The desktop is not working properly.

My left bar is not coming. Also, the options on the top right are not coming.

Please help me in restoring my desktop.

--
Prabodh Prakash

Answer (score 0):

Suggest that you restart your computer (If you are stuck on the desktop you can open a Terminal with the CTRL+ALT+T shortcut) with the command:

sudo shutdown - r now

command, and then drop into a recovery console.

From there, you will want to run the command:

unity - - reset

and allow that to complete before restarting your computer and then try to login again. This should reset your Unity back to the way that it was before the ccsm hang crashed the install.

Found that in my case, choosing the Crash Handler preference was the problem in ccsm, but suppose that YMMV in the usage of ccsm given the difference of video cards and drivers.

HTH. Have a nice day. :)